# programmatic grep command output

Tags: unix, grep

Is there a way to get XML or equivalent output of grep command that can be passed on to other programs.

For example, grep can give the file names, line numbers and context of the pattern matched.

Filename and line number extraction can be done using some split command with delimiter ':'. However, if the filename contains ':' character (I know it is weird, but there is a possibility), it would need lot more processing.

With the context (grep -C option), it becomes even more complex. If the context of two matches overlaps, grep optimizes the output and it will be difficult to separate.

So I am wondering if grep command can simply generate an XML or JSON like output that other programs can just load.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option `-Z` to `grep` which produces unambiguous output, by using Nul characters.

Comment: That's a good point. But, that only solves part of the problem.

Comment: You will have to write a little program, in Python, shell, perl or whatever you prefer.